# Почему не верно находит минимальный элемент матрицы

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

```
int matr[10][10];
int min = matr[0][0];
int max = matr[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) 
    {
        matr[i][k] = rand();
        cout << matr[i][k] << "\t";
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        if (matr[i][k] < min)
            min = matr[i][k];
    }
}
cout << endl << min << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        if (matr[i][k] > max)
            max = matr[i][k];
    }
}
cout << max << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

**В абсолютно любой матрице/массиве выдает минимальное значение int как результат, в то время как максимум находит верно**

> Цитата

Comment: Рандом возьмите поменьше matr[i][k] = rand() % 100;, а минимуму присвойте INT_MAX :  int min =  INT_MAX;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправим порядок действий:

```
int matr[10][10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) 
    {
        matr[i][k] = rand();
        cout << matr[i][k] << "\t";
    }
}

// мало ли что там было в matr[0][0], до инициализации
int min = matr[0][0];
int max = matr[0][0];

...
```